# Javascript regex to validate and retrieve string not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I tested the regular expression at the regex101.com and it works fine.
Now I need to write a javascript code to ask if there is a match and if it is true I need to retrieve the string "P01".
How do I retrieve the string that matched?

```
var tempHostname = "host01-P01abcde.contoso.net"

var re = new RegExp("([P]{1}[0-9]{2})");    //P01 P02 etc
if (re.test(tempHostname)) 
{
    logger.debug("Valid regex");
} 
else 
{
    logger.debug("Invalid regex");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: change Regex to `P[0-9]{2}`

Comment: I test with console.log and it says `Valid regex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the string that matched?

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) a way to achieve your result is:

```js
var tempHostname = "host01-P01abcde.contoso.net";

var re = new RegExp("P[0-9]{2}");    //P01 P02 etc
var result = tempHostname.match(re);
if (result != null) 
{
    console.log("Valid regex: " + result.pop());
} 
else 
{
    console.log("Invalid regex");
}

tempHostname = "host01-012abcde.contoso.net";
var result = tempHostname.match(re);
if (result != null) 
{
    console.log("Valid regex: " + result.pop());
} 
else 
{
    console.log("Invalid regex");
}
```

Comment: man thank you so much. Most importantly you pointed me out to a web site where I can test the snippets! that will help a lot!!!